# Calculating propensity functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to calculate propensity functions in python, using the equation: propensity function = stoch_rate*product of binom(xi, si)
where xi is the number of discrete molecules of a particular reactant in a reaction and si is the ratio between reactants in each equation, both stored in matrices.

```
popul_num = np.matrix([100, 200, 0, 0])
LHS = np.matrix([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]]) --> three rows for 3 different reactions, each row has 4 elements describing the ratio of reactants in that particular reaction
stoch_rate = np.matrix([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000]) --> rates for each of the three reactions above
```

My system has 4 entities; Enzyme, substrate, enzyme-substrate complex and product. Which are described in the popul_num and LHS matrices in that order.

I've written the following code to iterate over the elements of the matrices calculate the binomial coefficients for each reactant (based on number of molecules in popul_num and ratio in LHS) and then multiply by the rate constants to generate the propensity function.

```
for j in LHS:
aj = stoch_rate
for i in popul_num: 
    if np.any(i >= LHS[i,j]):
        # ^^^IndexError --> index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3^^^
        aj = list(aj*binom(i, LHS[i, j]))             
    else: 
        aj == 0 
        break
print(aj)
```

The if statement is meant check if the number of discrete molecules in popul_num is high enough to allow the reaction to happen according to the stochiometries/ratios in LHS.

I'm getting the index error: `index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`

I know indexing starts at zero and have tried to look up a few solutions but haven't had any look!

Any help would be much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the values in stead of the indexes in your for loops. Corrected code:

```
def stoch():
    popul_num = np.matrix([100, 200, 0, 0])
    LHS = np.matrix([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]]) #--> three rows for 3 different reactions, each row has 4 elements describing the ratio of reactants in that particular reaction
    stoch_rate = np.matrix([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000]) #--> rates for each of the three reactions above

    for j in range(len(LHS)):
        aj = stoch_rate
        for i in range(len(popul_num)):
            if np.any(i >= LHS[i,j]):
                aj = list(aj*binom(i, LHS[i, j]))             
        else: 
            aj == 0 
            break
    print(aj)
```

Output:

```
>>> stoch()
[[ 0.0016  0.0001  0.1   ]]
```